# Creating Controller Plugin No joint_name specified

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ubuntu, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having an issue with making the plugin works in Gazebo 9 and melodic in ubuntu 18.04. I'm keep getting these errors

```
[ERROR] [1653189634.080473330, 0.379000000]: No joint_name specified
[ERROR] [1653189634.080611896, 0.379000000]: Failed to initialize the controller
[ERROR] [1653189634.080791301, 0.379000000]: Initializing controller 'joint1_position_controller' failed
[INFO] [1653189634.710451, 1.015000]: Calling service /gazebo/set_model_configuration
[INFO] [1653189634.717597, 1.019000]: Set model configuration status: SetModelConfiguration: success
[spawn_urdf-4] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/bandar/.ros/log/214f367c-d97e-11ec-baf2-f07bcb42944d/spawn_urdf-4*.log
[ERROR] [1653189635.082707, 1.369000]: Failed to load joint1_position_controller
```

For `controller_plugins.xml` file, I have

```
<library path="lib/libmy_controller_lib">
    <class name="my_position_controller/MyPositionController" 
           type="my_controller_ns::MyPositionController"
           base_class_type="controller_interface::ControllerBase" />
</library>
```

I'm not sure what needs to be written in `class name=`. Should I type the name of the package or the name of namespace in my class? I've tried both but with no success. The shared library has been created successfully though. My source file is

```
namespace my_controller_ns 
{
    class MyPositionController : public controller_interface::Controller<hardware_interface::EffortJointInterface>
    {...}
}
```

The `.yaml` file is

```
rrbot:
  # Publish all joint states ------------------------
  joint_state_controller:
    type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
    publish_rate: 50

  # Position Controllers ----------------------------
  joint1_position_controller:
    type: my_position_controller/MyPositionController
    joint: joint1
    gain: 0.1
```

I'm totally sure the name of the joint is `joint1` and this is my source file related to this part

```
// retrieve the joint object to control
    std::string joint_name;
    if( !n.getParam("joint1", joint_name) ){
        ROS_ERROR("No joint_name specified");
        return false;
    }

    joint_ = hw->getHandle(joint_name);
    command_ = joint_.getPosition();
```

When I run

```
>rospack plugins --attrib=plugin controller_interface
```

I get this listed

```
my_position_controller /home/xxx/Desktop/RosControllers/catkin_ws1/src/my_position_controller/controller_plugins.xml
```

I also made sure the gazebo_ros and transmission tags are added

```
<!-- ***** Transmission Tags ***** -->
<transmission name="transmission1">
   <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
   <joint name="joint1">
     <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
   </joint>
   <actuator name="motor1">
     <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
     <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
   </actuator>
</transmission>

<!-- ros_control pluging -->
<gazebo>
   <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
       <robotNamespace>/rrbot</robotNamespace>
       <robotSimType>gazebo_ros_control/DefaultRobotHWSim</robotSimType>
   </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

Moreover, the namespace is consistent with the launch file

```
<node name="control_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
        output="screen" ns="/rrbot" args="joint_state_controller joint1_position_controller"/>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401102/creating-controller-plugin-no-joint_name-specified/) by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2022-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok I've solved this problem and I would like share it since a lot of people are complaining. The errors come usually as

```
1- Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface.
2- Failed to initialize the controller
3- Initializing controller 'joint1_position_controller' failed
```

This error pops up from different sources. **First**, make sure you installed all related control packages

```
ros-<rosdistro>-ros-control  ros-<rosdistro>-ros-controllers ros-<rosdistro>-gazebo-ros ros-<rosdistro>-gazebo-ros-control
```

**Second**, if you are using `namespace` as in the following line which is located in `.urdf` file

```
<gazebo>
        <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
            <robotNamespace>/rrbot</robotNamespace>
            <robotSimType>gazebo_ros_control/DefaultRobotHWSim</robotSimType>
        </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

Make sure you are using the same `namespace` in `.launch` and `.yaml` files which appears as `ns="/rrbot"`

```
 <node name="control_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
      output="screen" ns="/rrbot" args="joint1_position_controller"/>
```

and the `.yaml` may look like this

```
rrbot:
  # Publish all joint states ------------------------
  joint_state_controller:
    type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
    publish_rate: 50
    
  # Position Controllers ----------------------------
  joint1_position_controller:
    type: my_controller/MyPositionController
    joint: joint1
    gain: 0.1
```

If you are using your own plugin controller, you better check it is registered which can be done as (i.e. source your catkin_ws folder first)

```
rospack plugins --attrib=plugin controller_interface | grep my_controller
```

you should except to get something like this

```
my_controller /home/xxx/Desktop/RosControllers/catkin_ws1/src/my_controller/controller_plugins.xml
```

In my case none of the above solutions solved my problem. The interesting thing I found `getParam()` is not getting the correct joint name which in the source file as

```
bool MyPositionController::init(hardware_interface::EffortJointInterface* hw, ros::NodeHandle &n)
{
    // retrieve the joint object to control
    std::string joint_name;
    if( !n.getParam("joint1", joint_name) ){
        ROS_ERROR("No joint name specified");
        return false;
    }
     ....
}
```

when I type "joint" rather than "joint1" which represents the joint's name in my `.urdf`, the error gone. I've seen some books use `"joint_name"` which yields an error as well. I'm not sure if this is a new update or these books use old ros version which uses `joint_name` rather than `joint`. I'm using Gazebo 9 and Melodic in Ubuntu 18.04.

---

Originally posted by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) with karma: 155 on 2022-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-23**:
You're jumping to conclusions a bit I believe.

Here:

> ```
>   joint1_position_controller:
> ```

```
    type: my_position_controller/MyPositionController
    joint: joint1
```

In the last line, the *name* of the parameter would be `joint1_position_controller/joint`, *not* `joint1_position_controller/joint1`.

`joint1` is the *value*.

So this:

> ```
> n.getParam("joint1", joint_name)
> ```

cannot work, as there is no parameter with *the name* `joint1`. There is only a `joint` parameter, with *value* `joint1`.

This has nothing to do with namespaces or any of the other things you mentioned.

> when I type "joint" rather than "joint1" which represents the joint's name in my `.urdf`, the error gone

no, again, this is due to `joint` being the *name*, and `joint1` being the *value*.

You can only pass `getParam(..)` a *name*, not a value.

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2022-05-23**:
@gvdhoom thank you for the comment. I was following a book and the author put it as `joint_name` but since the error's message is same for other errors, it drove me nuts until I saw there is a problem with the parameter.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-23**:
Ok.

I still believe what you posted as an answer isn't really the answer, but you seem to be happy, so that is probably enough.